# How to get IP address on page load in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I'm working in an Angular4 project. I'm trying to get system IP address on page load and pass it to the API for storing the IP address in a MSSQL database. But two rows get inserted on each page load and the IP address in showing as "undefined".

This is my `app.component.ts` code

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{   
  publicIP;
  res;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() : void
  {
    this.getip();
    this.http.get("http://localhost:57036/api/data/GetClientIp/?
    IP_Address="+this.publicIP).subscribe(data=>{
    this.res=data as string[]});
  }

  getip()
  {
    this.http.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback').subscribe(data => {
    this.publicIP=data['ip'];});
  }
}
```

I got the IP address in data but while assigning the value to PublicIP it is showing as "Undefined"

```
this.http.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback').subscribe(data => {
this.publicIP=data['ip'];});
```

Comment: If you control the server, you can do that easier there. The server already receives the public API with the request.

Comment: Both calls are asynchronus. So when your second call to your localhost api is executed. The first call to freegeoip is not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two concurrent *dependent* asynchronous calls.

You need the IP from freegeoip before you can save it. So reverse your logic, and make use of [the `oncomplete` callback from an Observable subscription](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    publicIP: string;
    res: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback')
                 .subscribe(
                    data => this.publicIP = data['ip'], // Data from REST
                    error => console.error(error),      // Error callback
                    () => this.saveIP()                 // Once this call completes
                 );
    }

     saveIP() {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:57036/api/data/GetClientIp/?IP_Address=${this.publicIP}`)
                 .subscribe(data => this.res = data);
    }
}
```

But you don't need to save all this state, you can do it functionally, using only the `onnext` callback:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback')
                 .subscribe(
                    data => this.saveIP(data['ip']),
                    error => console.error(error)
                 );
    }

     saveIP(address: string) {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:57036/api/data/GetClientIp/?IP_Address=${address}`)
                 .subscribe(data => this.res = data);
    }
}
```

Comment: now I got the IP Address but for each page load it is inserting two rows(IP Address) in Database.